# Load a Picked or Joblib Pre trained ML Model to Sagemaker and host as endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

If I have a trained model in Using pickle, or Joblib.
Lets say its Logistic regression or XGBoost.

I would like to host that model in AWS Sagemaker as endpoint without running a training job.
How to achieve that.

```
#Lets Say myBucketName contains model.pkl
model = joblib.load('filename.pkl')  
# X_test = Numpy Array 
model.predict(X_test)
```

I am not interested to `sklearn_estimator.fit('S3 Train, S3 Validate' )` , I have the trained model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Scikit Learn for example, you can get inspiration from this public demo https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb

Step 1: Save your artifact (eg the joblib) compressed in S3 at `s3://<your path>/model.tar.gz`

Step 2: Create an inference script with the deserialization function `model_fn`. (Note that you could also add custom inference functions `input_fn`, `predict_fn`, `output_fn` but for scikit the defaults function work fine)

```
%%writefile inference_script.py. # Jupiter command to create file in case you're in Jupiter

import joblib
import os

def model_fn(model_dir):
    clf = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return clf
```

Step 3: Create a model associating the artifact with the right container

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.model import SKLearnModel

model = SKLearnModel(
    model_data='s3://<your path>/model.tar.gz',
    role='<your role>',
    entry_point='inference_script.py',
    framework_version='0.23-1')
```

Step 4: Deploy!

```
model.deploy(
    instance_type='ml.c5.large',  # choose the right instance type
    initial_instance_count=1)
```

Comment: Well, this one seems to search a validation file. ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation:

Comment: Can you check the CloudWatch logs? They'll have more details (in the console: SageMaker / Training / your training job / At the bottom of the page: logs